# What is the quality setting in Ultimaker Cura do? (Super, Dynamic, Standard, Low)

Tags: ultimaker-cura

In the Ultimaker Cura print settings menu, there is a dropdown menu labeled "profiles", with Super Quality, Dynamic Quality, Standard Quality, and Low Quality. What do these settings do exactly? If I set it to Super Quality for example, it changes things like the layer height settings, but I am able to then change those settings back to whatever I want and profile remains on Super Quality.

What are these quality settings? I know this is probably an obvious question but I am basically a beginner and for some reason can find little info on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Ultimaker Support](https://support.ultimaker.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012606599-Quality-settings) website, these are called "Quality settings". You could think of them as "resolution" settings.

There are 3 different adjustments made when changing these settings:

- Layer height
- Initial layer height
- Line width

A smaller layer height will produce a smoother surface. Initial layer height can create a stronger adhesion to the build plate. Line width will determine how much plastic material will be extruded.